# set div style to max-height

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have a question about css styling, where I want to set max-height to outer . When I set only height it works fine, but when I want to set it to max-height the content of the inner  disappears.

You can get the example here: http://sara.hil.ch/grega/example5.html

Any suggestions?

```
//outer div  style
 div.dogodkiinhalt {  
      position: relative; 
      top: 0px;   
      left: 0px;   
      width: 400px;  
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      background: blue; 
      border: none;  
      overflow: auto; 
      visibility: visible; 
      height: 200px;

    }
//inner div style
    #inhaltbox { 
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px; 
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      display: none;
      display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Use both: height and max-height. It works fine

Comment: What browser is this happening in?

Comment: it's the same on firefox on mac or win.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you set `max-height` - what will the minimum height be? ZERO!

You need to set `min-height` or `height` as well.

Also, there are a few problems here.

```
 div.dogodkiinhalt {  
      position: relative; 
      top: 0px;   <-- not needed
      left: 0px;   <--- not needed
      width: 400px;  
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      background: blue; 
      border: none;  
      overflow: auto; 
      visibility: visible; <--- not needed 
      height: 200px;

    }
//inner div style
    #inhaltbox { 
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px; <--- left or right also needs to be declared
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      display: none;  <---
      display: block; <--- Choose one, not both
    }
```

Comment: ok, but how can i set the height of div container to fit to text? you know.. if i put in less text than conatainers height must be smaller that it is. how can i set that?

Comment: @greg Do you have any text to begin with? It sounds like when you experienced your disapearing DIV you had nothing in it. Is that correct?

Comment: Because if you only have `max-height` (and not `min-height` or `height`) then your DIV should only be as high as the content inside it.